# Moodle - Add dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, moodle

Good day.

I'm trying to add a new dropdown menu on the page where we edit a question. This dropdown menu is used for my local plugin. I didn't manage to modify the page and add the select tag.

It should look like this. (I used 'Inspect element' in achieving this)
[image]

I created a table that will contain the `question id` and `obe category` for the question since it's not a good practice to modify Moodle's defined tables.

I manually created the table but I will use XMLDB Editor soon. I'm still reading on it, will apply it later on.

Sample table structure with content.

`mdl_question_obe`

```
  id     question    obe_category
  1         1            FI
  2         2            FI
  3         3            S
  4         4            S
```

`question` is the id of the question, `obe_category` is the category of the question.

I think that there are other modifications to be done once this is achieved because the `mdl_question_obe` table will be populated after the question is saved.

How can I achieve this? Any insights will do!

And please leave a comment if I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

In `/question/question.php`

before `$mform->set_data($toform);` add this to get the current obe category

```
if ($id) {
    $toform->obe_category = $DB->get_field('question_obe', 'obe_category', array('question' => $id));
}
```

Then in `/question/type/edit_question_form.php`

before `$mform->addElement('editor', 'questiontext', get_string('questiontext', 'question'),`

add this

```
$obe_options('FI' => 'FI', 'S' => 'S', 'M' => 'M');
```

or if the values are stored in a database table then use this, assuming the table is called obe_category and the text field is called obe_category

```
$obe_options = $DB->get_records_menu('obe_category', array(), 'obe_category', 'obe_category, obe_category');
```

then

```
$mform->addElement('select', 'obe_category',
            get_string('selectobecategory', 'local_obe_category'), $obe_options);
$mform->setType('obe_category', PARAM_ALPHA);
```

Then back in `/question/question.php`

just after `$question = $qtypeobj->save_question($question, $fromform);`

add an update / insert

```
if ($question_obe = $DB->get_record('question_obe', array('question' => $question->id)) {
    $question_obe->obe_category = $fromform->obe_category;
    $DB->update_record('question_obe', $question_obe);
} else {
    $question_obe = new stdClass();
    $question_obe->question = $question->id;
    $question_obe->obe_category = $fromform->obe_category;
    $DB->insert_record('question_obe', $question_obe);
}
```

Comment: I apologize for the late response. This really helped me!